# How to reset a List to its initial state

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, filter

I am a beginner when it comes to AndroidStudio and I am developing this app, where I am having problems with filtering information from a firebase database. When clicking on switch1 (activating it), I get the filtered Informations, but when I deactivate it, I don't get a list with all Infos but only the filtered ones added one more time. The part of the code that's supposed to be responsible for that is commented under //delivery service

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private AppModel appModel;

//Datenkategorien
private boolean[] checkedDK;

//Betriebsart
private boolean[] checkedBA;

//Produktgruppe
private boolean[] checkedPr;


private String[] orgaList;

//bzw. Liste aus Organization-Objekte getname().toString
//final Organization[] organisations = ...;
private boolean[] checkedOrgas;
private List<Company> companies;
private ListView listView;
private CompanyAdapter adapter;
private int layout;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_main);

    layout = R.layout.company_list;
    appModel = new AppModel();

    //Daten von FireStore ablesen und konvertieren
    ParseData parseData = new ParseData(db, appModel);
    parseData.parseFrom();



    //Liste von Betrieben aus dem Datenbank
    companies = appModel.getCompanies();
    

    checkedDK = new boolean[getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dataCategories).length];
    checkedBA = new boolean[getResources().getStringArray(R.array.betriebsarten).length];
    checkedPr = new boolean[getResources().getStringArray(R.array.products).length];
    checkedOrgas = new boolean[4];

    this.listView = findViewById(R.id.companiesList);

    this.adapter = new CompanyAdapter(this, this.layout, this.companies,false);
    this.listView.setAdapter(this.adapter);

    //Swicth, ob alle Informationen gezeigt werden sollen
    SwitchCompat allInfo = findViewById(R.id.switch3);
    allInfo.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
        if(isChecked) {
            this.adapter.setChecked(true);
            this.layout = R.layout.all_info_company;
        } else {
            this.adapter.setChecked(false);
            this.layout = R.layout.company_list;
        }
        this.adapter.setLayout(this.layout);
        this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    });

    //delivery service
    SwitchCompat deliveryService = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    deliveryService.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
        if(isChecked) {
            companies.removeIf(company -> !company.hasDeliveryService());
        } else {
            this.companies = this.appModel.getCompanies();

        }
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(companies);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
```

Here is the other class used (not the full code, Company is a self-defined class):

```
public class AppModel {
List<Company> companies;
List<DataCategory> dataCategories;

List<String> organizationsName;
List<Types> companyTypes;
List<Categories> productCategories;
boolean isOpen;
TimeInterval openingHours;
boolean deliveryService;


public AppModel(){
    this.companies = new ArrayList<>();
    this.dataCategories = new ArrayList<>();
    this.organizationsName = new ArrayList<>();
    this.companyTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    this.productCategories = new ArrayList<>();
    this.isOpen = false;
    this.deliveryService = false;
}



public List<Company> getCompanies() {
    return companies;
}
```

I tried creating another ArrayList temp = new ArrayList(); and then temp.addAll(companies) and only after that altering companies and by else clearing companies and then addAll(temp) but it didn't work

Comment: You are removing the entries from company list. think like a way. you have 10 box in front of you. you removed 5. now to complete the list either you need to add back removed boxes of you can maintain copy of full this to replace to original state

Comment: @KaranjotSingh yes I understand that the problems lays by removeIf, but how else can I filter a list without removing elements and I tried it with a copy of companies but it didn't work either

Comment: Keep the copy of full list when you deactivate replace companies with that copy

Comment: @KaranjotSingh would you mind being more concrete cause I tried many ways with a copy and none of those worked.

Comment: use this instead of removing. this.companies = appModel.getCompanies().stream().filter(company -> !company.hasDeliveryService()).collect(Collectors.toList())

Comment: hope that worked

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use same AppModel instance when you uncheck. That's why you got already filtered value again. try this code instead.

```
deliveryService.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
        if(isChecked) {
            appModel = new AppModel();
            companies = appModel.getCompanies();
            companies.removeIf(company -> !company.hasDeliveryService());
        } else {
            appModel = new AppModel();
            companies = appModel.getCompanies();
           
        }
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(companies);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
```